# Nagios compilation error on Centos

Tags: nagios, centos7

I am trying to install Nagios 4 on a Centos 7 machine using the instructions found [here](http://www.tecmint.com/install-nagios-in-linux/). When I get to the compilation and input `make all` I get this error:

```
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `../include/locations.h’, needed by ‘nagios.o’. Stop.
```

I have followed these instructions to the letter but I cannot go further. What to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was missing the perl and perl-devel packages.

Comment: I am the original author. I found the solution after a bit more searching and posted it here as an answer.